# Supabase: what's the difference between stored procedures, RPC's, database functions, etc

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, rpc, supabase

So I've got basic knowledge of database programming and I'm trying to set up my Supabase database to access it via a Flutter app. I'd like to do so using "Stored procedures" so all access is through well-defined functions.

Before diving too far I want to make sure I'm using the right methods, and I'm running into all sorts of nomenclature that may or may not be pointing to the same thing.

For what I'm trying to do I am seeing:

- "[**Postgres functions**](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/rpc)" that seem to be what I want
- [This article](https://medium.com/geekculture/using-stored-procedures-rpc-in-supabase-to-increment-a-like-counter-9c5b2293a65b), pointing that "**RPC**"'s are a way to access them
- [This article](https://www.reddit.com/r/Supabase/comments/10px6de/edge_functions_or_database_functions/) stating there are "**Database functions**" and "**Edge functions**"
- Documentation mentions [Database triggers](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/postgres/triggers) which seem to be just a different way of triggering Postgres functions (but the link that would clinch it is 404…)

So my current conclusions, which I would like to confirm, are:

1. **Stored procedures**, **Postgres functions** and **Database functions** are synonymous in this context? "Database functions" in particular feels ambiguous.
2. **RPC** are a way of calling them externally
3. **Database triggers** are a way of calling them automatically upon certain triggers
4. **Edge functions** are a different animal (higher-level Typescript AWS Lambda-style more external-oriented functionality).
5. **"Supabase functions"** are a bit ambiguous, but I believe [refer to EDGE functions](https://supabase.com/blog/supabase-functions-updates) (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, nailed it! Stored Procedures and Postgres Functions are synonymous. Edge Functions are a separate serverless function that run within Deno. RPC is the way you call Postgres Functions from the Supabase client